Indexing rear gears mountain bike
Bought an old bike to get back on the road, all good until indexing the gears.
It's twist shifts on the handle bars, 7 rear 3 front.
I've replaced the gear cables, sheaths, chain and Shimano parts throughout matched to the frame and model.
The rear highest gear #7 at the handlebar is selected. Chain on smallest/highest/7 gear rear and smallest/highest front/#3. All seems to align when moved manually.
Rear adjuster screwed all the way in and half a turn out.
Handlebar twist shift from (highest) #7 to #6 does nothing when turning the adjuster on the derailleur anticlockwise.
Shifting handlebar to #1 and shifting to #2 will move to the second highest (2nd smallest outer cog) and third highest when adjusting the rear derailleur anticlockwise. Cant get it to go any lower i.e. cassette 4, 3, 2 and 1 just unreachable seemingly.
I'm new to these types of gear systems they were simpler when I was a kid :-D and still suffering brain fog, so struggling to figure this out. The apparent reverse order 1-7 on the twist grip not corresponding high to low on the cassette is adding to my inability to determine what's going on. I'm ok with having this all "a about f" just need some direction to try.

Go through this, https://www.parktool.com/en-int/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment . Best to ignore the numbers on the shifter, if the adjustment is done right, they will fall into line (reverse order from what you expect may happen, it's just a label.)  Likely the cable needs tensioning.
